# Association named not found, perhaps you misspelled it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have multiple associations:

`User`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :family_tree, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :memberships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :nodes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :participants, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments
```

`Node`

```
class Node < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PublicActivity::Model
  tracked except: :update, owner: ->(controller, model) { controller && controller.current_user }

  belongs_to :family_tree
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :media, polymorphic: true, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :node_comments, dependent: :destroy
```

`Notification`

```
class Notification < PublicActivity::Activity
  acts_as_readable :on => :created_at
end
```

I am using the public_activity gem, and when I do this in my `ApplicationController`:

```
  @unread_act = Notification.where(owner_id: current_user).includes(trackable: { user: :node}).unread_by(current_user)
```

I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationNotFoundError at /
Association named 'node' was not found on User; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

Even when I tried this Vanilla version:

```
  @unread_act = Notification.where(owner_id: current_user).includes(:node).unread_by(current_user)
```

I got this error:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationNotFoundError at /
Association named 'node' was not found on Notification; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

What could be causing this?

**Edit 1**

When I tried just doing a `includes(:trackable)`, given that I am using the bullet gem, to try and track down N+1 errors, I got this message:

```
N+1 Query detected
  Node => [:user]
  Add to your finder: :include => [:user]

N+1 Query detected
  Node => [:media]
  Add to your finder: :include => [:media]
N+1 Query method call stack
```

So everything I am doing is trying to reduce these N+1 query issues.

Comment: Did you try using the plural 'nodes'? Since that's how its defined in your has_many

Comment: Yep....I tried that too: `ActiveRecord::AssociationNotFoundError at /
Association named 'nodes' was not found on Notification; perhaps you misspelled it?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the correct way to approach this is by using an array on the `trackable` attribute like so:

```
@unread_act = Notification.where(recipient_id: current_user).includes(:trackable => [:user, :node]).unread_by(current_user).order("created_at desc")
```

The main part is:

`includes(:trackable => [:user, :node])`

This seems to have worked beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

`Node` is your `trackable` object in PublicActivity terms. It's a polymorphic association that allows you to use your `Node` class as well as any other model.

That's why you should try `includes(:trackable)` instead. With the example from the controller: `@unread_act = Notification.where(owner_id: current_user).includes(trackable: { user: :nodes}).unread_by(current_user)`.

Also note that you're deriving your own `Notification` class from `PA::Activity`, that probably won't work well with acts_as_readable. Try p_a wiki to learn how to extend the class.

Comment: I tried that, but I still get an N+1 issue - which is why I am trying to eager_load all of these objects. Any ideas on how I can eager load :node, :user, and :trackable in that one call?

Comment: I updated the question with details on the `n+1` issue I am trying to squash.

Comment: Also I am not seeing any articles in the p_a wiki that show you how to extend the class - https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity/wiki. Do you have a specific one in mind that you can point me to?